# c++ how to solve my memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, copy-constructor

Consider the following implemntation of a Binary class representation of an integer:

```
class Binary {
private:
    int *digits;
    int first1;
public:
    Binary() {
        digits = new int[128];
        digits[0]=0;
        first1=0;
    }
    ~Binary() {
        cout<<"deleting"<<endl;
        delete [] digits;
    }
    Binary(const Binary& b){
        digits = new int[128];
        memcpy(digits,b.digits,128*sizeof(int));
        first1=b.first1;
    }
    explicit Binary(double x){
        int n=(int)x,i;
        digits = new int[128];
        for (i=0; n ; i++,n>>=1) digits[i]=(n & 1)? 1:0;
        first1=i-1;
    }
    Binary& operator =(const Binary& b){
        if (this==&b) return *this;
        memcpy(digits,b.digits,128*sizeof(int));
        first1=b.first1;
        return *this;
    }
    Binary(int n) {
        int i;
        digits = new int[128];
        for (i=0; n ; i++,n>>=1) digits[i]=(n & 1)? 1:0;
        first1=i-1;
    }
    void print() {
        for (int i=first1; i>=0 ; i--) cout<<digits[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
    operator int() {
        int x = 1,sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<=first1 ; i++,x<<=1) sum+=digits[i]*x;
        return sum;
    }
    Binary& operator +(Binary& a) {
        int overflow = 0;
        Binary* b1=new Binary();
        int max = a.first1>this->first1? a.first1 : this->first1,bit;
        for (int i=0; i<=max ; i++) {
            bit=a.digits[i]+this->digits[i]+overflow;
            overflow=0;
            if (bit>1) overflow=1;
            b1->digits[i]=bit%2;
        }
        return *b1;
    }

};
```

and the main using it:

```
int main() {
    Binary b(91);
    int x=9;
    Binary *b2=new Binary();
    *b2=b+x;
    x=*b2;
    b2->print();
    cout<<" = "<<x;
    cin>>x;
}
```

lets talk about the line:

```
*b2=b+x;
```

first the compiler implicitly allocates a new binary instance for int x, then using it as a paramater for the addition, then creates a new binary instance for the addition result and copies it bit by bit to *b2.

The problem is, that if you run this code, it only prints deleting ONCE, while there were 2 objects created for the execution of the command. apparently there's a leak comes from the addition code, in which i explicitly created a new object to return the result.

**Q1**: am i correct?

**Q2**: what can i do to overcome this?

**EDIT**:
The answer and more about the topic of operator overloading can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: Your `operator+` should return `Binary`, not `Binary&` and it should not dynamically allocate an object.

Comment: I'm curious why it even compiled because you don't have overloaded operator+(int)

Comment: @Blood: He has an implicit conversion constructor from int, so an object is created, then passed to `operator+`.

Comment: In regards to **Q2**, start by replacing `int* digits` with `std::vector<int> digits` and eliminating all calls to `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you lose the carry out of the top bit in your + routine.

Comment: Constructor from `double` is wrong: `int` has usually 32 bits (even on most x64 platforms – it depends on compiler) and `double` is 64-bit. And also (that's what I've thought after seeing your class name and it got me confused) – this would be wrong behaviour: your class says, that it contains given number in binary, so just casting it to `int` isn't expected at all. You should show binary representation of floating-point number, not just integer parts of it in U2.

Comment: @Archie, i didnt mention it because its off topic, but the task was to present the floor of a double, therefore int was simple enough.

Comment: @James, I agree that it would work, but then you wont be able to do something like A=B=C, which ref allows.

Comment: Would be nice to see some comments in code

Comment: @OfekRon: James said that `operator+` should return by value not reference, and he's right.  How does that relate to `A=B=C`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: Objects allocated with `new` must be deleted with `delete`.  Objects allocated with `new[]` must be deleted with `delete[]`.  Globals and locals are deleted automatically when their scope/TU execution ends.  In `Binary& operator +(Binary& a)` you make a `Binary` that is leaked, and in `main` you make another `Binary` that is leaked.

These problems would be avoided if wrote `operator+` like so:

```
Binary operator +(Binary& a) const{ //return by value
    Binary b1(*this); //hold it on the stack
    //math here
    return b1; //return by value
}
```

and if in main you avoided allocation as well:

```
Binary b2 = b+x;
x = b2;
b2.print();
```

This will be faster than your original code, is easier to read and understand, and won't leak.

[Other notes]

Use a `std::vector` for the internal data instead of managing your own dynamic array.  `vector` is easier, and less likely to make mistakes.

It's usually best to make conversions (like `int` -> `Binary`) explicit wherever you can.  It adds typing, but saves headaches.  This goes for your `int` conversion operator as well.

Make your const functions const.   Right now, if you get a `const Binary`, you can't do *almost anything* with it.  You can't print it, you can't add anything to it...

You appear to be storing one bit per `int`, which means you're using about 97% more space than needed (wasting 99.99999995% of the values), which is just silly.  Most novices start with `0-9` per `char`, which only wastes 50% of the space. (though that's still 96% of the values), but is really easy to understand.

The normal way to do addition is like this:

```
Binary& operator+=(const Binary& rhs) { 
    int max = a.first1>this->first1? a.first1 : this->first1,bit;
    for (int i=0; i<=max ; i++) {
        bit=a.digits[i]+this->digits[i]+overflow;
        overflow=0;
        if (bit>1) overflow=1;
        b1->digits[i]=bit%2;
    }
}  
Binary friend operator+(Binary lhs, const Binary& rhs) {  
{return lhs+=rhs;}
```

Comment: Great, thanks!, one more thing tho, I added delete to the allocation in main and used a some plugin to check if there were any leaks and it said there arent any, how come?

Comment: and why did u declare it freind?

Comment: @OfekRon: if you have two `new` and only one `delete`, then the plugin is wrong.  I declared it friend so that the left side can take advantage of conversions.  That's the normal way to do it.  With `operator+=` as a member taking one argument, and `operator+` as a `friend` taking two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you really see "deleting" only once, than this must be the variable b. `*b2 = b+x` may be done by converting b to int, adding x, constructing a Binary from it and copying that to the place where b2 points to. As b2 is just a raw pointer, you are leaking the initial *b2 instance and the one that overwrites it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not deleting b2 at the end of main.

Also operator should return by value, not returning an allocated Binary object as that will leak because C++ is not garbage collected

Also operator+ should take a const reference.

Also, print, operator+ and operator int should be const member functions

Also, you don't need to dynamically allocate the 128 ints, just make it an array of 128 ints

```
private:
    int digits[128];
```

and remove the delete on digits

also, you should initialize it in the constructor with

```
memset(digits, 0, sizeof(digits));
```